# interpolate cause `node cannot be cast to number`

Tags: react-native, animation, react-native-reanimated

An re-animation (1.13) is used to toggle accordion in React Native app. When accordion is open or close, an arrow is up or down. `interpolate` is used to animate when arrow from up to down or vise verse.

```
import Animated, { useValue, interpolate, Easing, useCode, State, greaterThan, lessThan } from "react-native-reanimated";
const animatedController = useValue(0); //<<==animated value between [0, 1]
const arrowAngle = interpolate(animatedController, {  //<<==interpolate causes error of node cannot be cast to number
    inputRange: [0, 0.5, 1],
    outputRange: ['0rad', `${0.5*Math.PI}rad`,`${Math.PI}rad`],
    extrapolate: Extrapolate.CLAMP,
  });

return (
    <>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => setOpen(!open)}>
        <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
          <Text>{title}</Text>
          <Animated.View style={{ transform: [{ rotateZ: arrowAngle }] }}> //<<==arrowAngle call here
            <Icon name="chevron-down-outline" size={20}  />
          </Animated.View>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </>
)
```

However the method above causes the error of `node cannot be cast to number` as below. This interpolate seems very simple. What's wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The output range shall be a number like this:

```
const arrowAngle = interpolate(animatedController, {
    inputRange: [0, 0.5, 1],
    outputRange: [0.01, 1/2*Math.PI,Math.PI],  //<<==shall be digital
    extrapolate: Extrapolate.CLAMP,
  });
```